# Something about JvPatchFile component?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2, jedi, jedi-code-library

I looked everywhere, but couldn't find anything related to this component, please could you give me some advice on how to use it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

TJvPatchFile is a TJvComponent descendant that implements a file patching utility.
TJvPatchFile can be used to apply patches in the Differences property to the contents of an original file in order to yield a file with the desired content. Values in the Differences property are in a specific format required by the TJvPatchFile component.
A design-time property editor is provided for the Differences property that can be used to create patches in the format required for use i the component. Patches for the specified files are encrypted using the Password provided at design-time.
Patches in the Differences property can be saved to a file for subsequent distribution and processing using the TJvPatchFile component.
When patches are applied using the Patch method, the updated file content can be overwritten in the original file or stored in a new file with the updated content. Applying patches in the Differences property requires the Password used when creating the list of file differences.

from http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvPatchFile

Comment: Thanks, but there would be an example on how to use it?